# how to write as geometric series $\dfrac{A(3s-5)}{(s-3)(3s-5)}+\dfrac{B(s-3)}{(3s-5)(s-3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

How would I write $\dfrac{A(3s-5)}{(s-3)(3s-5)}+\dfrac{B(s-3)}{(3s-5)(s-3)}$ as a sum of geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $|s|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1-s}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k$$
To get each term in your expression into this form is just a matter of rewriting. Take this simple example:
$$\frac{1}{2-x}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^k$$